# How to make ion-header-bar draggable?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have many tags want to be displayed in ion-header-bar which can't be in just one screen, Is it possible to make ion-header-bar draggable? like following gif of app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QixZ4.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: Basically I think you need a tab view which can also be dragged?

Comment: Hi, @Atula: thanks for your concerns. Is there any examples? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find can use ion-scroll, check it:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/